# Avoid double history record resulting from Keycloak JavaScript adapter redirect

Tags: javascript, back-button, back, keycloak, keycloak-services

I'm building an application that uses the [Keycloak JavaScript adapter](http://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_javascript_adapter) to authenticate.  As part of this process, the Keycloak JavaScript library redirects the user from my application to its authentication page, and then redirects the user back to my application once the user has been authenticated.

Unfortunately, this results in *two* browser history records for my application.  This means that if someone follows a link to my application and tries to use the browser's back button, they won't be able to leave the page - they'll be brought "back" to the page they are already on.

Is there a way to configure the Keycloak JS adapter so that it removes the history record it creates when it redirects the user from its authentication page back to my application?

Comment: After a bit more investigation, I've opened a bug for this behavior here: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-5831.